# How to convert an array of array of Doubles to an RDD[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I need to convert an `Array[Array[Double]]` to an `RDD`, e.g `[[1.1, 1.2 ...], [2.1, 2.2 ...], [3.1, 3.2 ...], ...]` to

`+-----+-----+-----+
 | 1.1 | 1.2 | ... |
 | 2.1 | 2.2 | ... |
 | 3.1 | 3.2 | ... |
 | ... | ... | ... |
 +-----+-----+-----+`

```
val testDensities: Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(1.1, 1.2), Array(2.1, 2.2), Array(3.1, 3.2))
val testData = spark.sparkContext
  .parallelize(Seq(testDensities
    .map { x => x.toArray }
      .map { x => x.toString() } ))
```

And this code even feels incorrect, the second map call is supposed to map each element in the array to convert the Double to String. This is what I get when I save it as a text file.

`[Ljava.lang.String;@773d7a60`

Can anybody please comment on what should I do, and where I am doing a horrendous mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
scala> val testDensities: Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(1.1, 1.2), Array(2.1, 2.2), Array(3.1, 3.2))
scala> val strRdd = sc.parallelize(testDensities).map(_.mkString("[",",","]"))
strRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[16] at map at <console>:26
scala> strRdd.collect
res7: Array[String] = Array([1.1,1.2], [2.1,2.2], [3.1,3.2])
```

But I have two question:

- Why do you want to do it? I understand that is only because you are
  learning and you are playing with Spark.
- Why do you try to use "Array"? It is not the first time that I see people trying to transform all in arrays. **Keep RDD until the end** and use more generic collections types.

Why is your code wrong:
Because you apply the map in your local array (in the Driver) and then create a RDD from a list of lists.
So:

- You are not parallelizing the execution of the maps. In fact, you are parallelizing nothing.
- You create an RDD of Lists and not of String.

If you execute your code in the console:

```
scala> val testData = sc.parallelize(Seq(testDensities.map { x => x.toArray }.map { x => x.toString() } ))
testData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[14] at parallelize at <console>:26
```

the response is clear: `RDD[Array[String]]`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the results of kernel density estimation in an array or array of Doubles and I wanted to visualize these results in Apache Zeppelin. Your solution did work, but I am accepting the other one as accepted as they answered before you. Thank though. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, really makes everything clear. Marked it as accepted answer for detailed explanation.

Comment: @angelcervera You have basically copied my answer

Comment: @cheseaux Sorry man, I did not copy. Responding at the same time, but I always try to response with more detail. No a lot of possible response :) People is learning so is good to explain, no only try to response fast to take scores.

Comment: Some machine learning algorithms in Spark require `Array[Array[Double]]` and not RDD's, e.g. OLSMultipleLinearRegression. Besides, if you want to manipulate those machine learning algorithms using RDD's but the original implementation is already using RDD's, you might have nested RDD's issues. This is probably one of the reasons you see people doing stuff with arrays (at least in my case)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert an Array[Double] to a String you can use the [mkString](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.5.1/scala/Iterable.html#mkString%28String%29) method which joins each item of the array with a delimiter (in my example `","`)

```
scala> val testDensities: Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(1.1, 1.2), Array(2.1, 2.2), Array(3.1, 3.2))
scala> val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(testDensities)
scala> val rddStr = rdd.map(_.mkString(","))

rddStr: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[7] at map at 

scala> rddStr.collect.foreach(println)
1.1,1.2
2.1,2.2
3.1,3.2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I accepted it as an answer as it perfectly does what I wanted, had to accept the other one because of the detailed explanation of what I was doing wrong. Thanks.